# Combining two API requests in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I'm working on a small application that uses NASA's Open API. I currently have a controller for each request, depending on the rover the photos are being returned for. I'd like to combine these two controllers into one while being able to select the rover in which photos are returned.

```
app.controller('OpportunityController', function($scope, $http) {

  // get date
  let today = new Date();
  let dd = today.getDate() - 5;
  let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
  }
  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

  // set variables
  $scope.baseUrl = "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/";
  $scope.rover = ["Opportunity"];
  $scope.date_params = "/photos?earth_date=" + today;
  $scope.searchParams = $scope.rover + $scope.date_params;
  $scope.key = "&api_key=API_KEY";

  // request
  $http.get($scope.baseUrl + $scope.searchParams + $scope.key)
      .success(function(result) {
          $scope.photos = result.photos;
          console.log($scope.photos);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
});

app.controller('MarsController', function($scope, $http) {

    // get date
    let today = new Date();
    let dd = today.getDate()-1;
    let mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    }
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    }
    today = yyyy+ '-' +mm+ '-' +dd;

    // set variables
    $scope.baseUrl = "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/";
    $scope.rover = ["Curiosity"];
    $scope.date_params = "/photos?earth_date=" + today;
    $scope.searchParams = $scope.rover + $scope.date_params;
    $scope.key = "&api_key=API_KEY";

    // request
    $http.get($scope.baseUrl + $scope.searchParams +  $scope.key)
        .success(function(result) {
            $scope.photos = result.photos;
            console.log($scope.photos);
        })
        .error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

dont see a problem

```
$http.get($scope.baseUrl + $scope.searchParams + $scope.key)
      .success(function(result) {
          $scope.photos = result.photos;
          console.log($scope.photos);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
$http.get($scope.baseUrl + $scope.searchParams + $scope.key)
      .success(function(result) {
          $scope.photos = result.photos;
          console.log($scope.photos);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
```